# TYPO3 ConnectionPool find a file after the uid of the file reference and update data

Tags: typo3, hook, typo3-8.x, filereference, connection-pool

The concept is that, after a successfull save of my object, it should update a text in the database (With a Hook). Lets call the field '**succText**'. The table i would like to access is the sys_file but i only get the sys_file_reference id when i save the object. So i thought i could use the ConnectionPool to select the sys_file **row** of this file reference and then insert the data on the field '**succText**'.

I tried this:

```
public function processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(array &$fieldArray, $table, $id, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj) {
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_file_reference');
    $findItemsId = $queryBuilder
       ->select('*')
       ->from('sys_file_reference')
       ->join(
          'sys_file_reference',
          'sys_file',
          'reference',
          $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('reference.uid', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('uid_local'))
       )
       ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid_local', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($fieldArray['downloads'], \PDO::PARAM_INT))
       )
      ->execute();
}
```

But this give me back the sys_file_reference id and not the id and the field values of the sys_file table.

As for the update, i havent tried it yet, cause i haven't figured out yet, how to get the row that needs to be updated. I gues with a subquery after the row is found, i don't really know.

The **processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray** is going to be renamed to post. I only have it this way in order to get the results on the backend.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to make use of the FileRepository class here.

```
$fileRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileRepository::class);
$fileObjects = $fileRepository->findByRelation('tablename', 'fieldname', $uid);
```

Where $uid is the ID of the record that the files are connected to via file reference.

You will get back an array of file objects to deal with.

Comment: Yes i already did, and i resolved the problem. Thanks you anyways :)

Comment: So could you please mark the answer as correct and the question as answered, so that other people might find it later on?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by removing the first code and adding a filerepository instance.

```
 $fileRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FileRepository::class);
 $fileObjects = $fileRepository->findByRelation('targetTable', 'targetField', $uid);
```

**VERY IMPORTANT!**

If you are creating a new element then TYPO3 assigns a temp **UID** variable with a name that looks like this **NEW45643476**. In order to get the $uid from the processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations you need to add this code before you get the instance of the fileRepository.

```
if (GeneralUtility::isFirstPartOfStr($uid, 'NEW')) {
    $uid = $pObj->substNEWwithIDs[$uid];
 }
```

Now as far as the text concerns, i extracted from a pdf. First i had to get the basename of the file in order to find its storage location and its name. Since i have only one file i don't really need a foreach loop and i can use the [0] as well. So the code looked like this:

```
$fileID = $fileObjects[0]->getOriginalFile()->getProperties()['uid'];
$fullPath[] = [PathUtility::basename($fileObjects[0]->getOriginalFile()->getStorage()->getConfiguration()['basePath']), PathUtility::basename($fileObjects[0]->getOriginalFile()->getIdentifier())];
```

This, gives me back an array looking like this:

```
array(1 item)
   0 => array(2 items)
      0 => 'fileadmin' (9 chars)
      1 => 'MyPdf.pdf' (9 chars)
```

Now i need to save the text from every page in a variable. So the code looks like this:

```
$getPdfText = '';
foreach ($fullPath as $file) {
    $parser = new Parser();
    $pdf    = $parser->parseFile(PATH_site . $file[0] . '/' . $file[1]);
    $pages  = $pdf->getPages();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
         $getPdfText .= $page->getText();
     }
  }
```

Now that i have my text i want to add it on the database so i will be able to use it on my search action. I now use the connection pool to get the file from the sys_file.

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_file');
$queryBuilder
      ->update('sys_file')
      ->where(
          $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($fileID))
        )
        ->set('pdf_text', $getPdfText)
        ->execute();
```

Now everytime i choose a PDF from my extension, i save its text on the database.

**EXTRA CONTENT**

If you want to include the PDFParser as well and you are on composer mode, then add this on your composer.json:

```
"smalot/pdfparser" : "*"
```

and on the autoload:

```
"Smalot\\PdfParser\\" : "Packages/smalot/pdfparser/src/"
```

Then under: **yourExtension/Classes/Hooks/DataHandler.php** add the namespace:

```
use Smalot\PdfParser\Parser;
```

Now you are able to use the `getPages()` and `getText()` functions.

The [Documentation](https://pdfparser.org/documentation)

If i missed something let me know and i will add it.